# how to write condition on includes in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have association between user and posts as user has many posts.
My query like `User.includes(:posts).all`. I would like to write where condition on posts but i got error invalid includes

```
User.includes(:posts,with: -> (posts) {where(post.likes > 100)}


include Mongoid::Document
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
User.includes(:posts).where("posts.likes", > 100)
```

Comment: i am doing in mongodb

Comment: yes , iam using mongoDb as database. Mongoid is ODM .

Comment: Try this `User.includes(:posts).where("posts.likes.gt" => 100)`